# Remember values across app sessions

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a text field within my app.

When a user inputs text I need a way to "remember" the value in the text field so that it can be recalled if the user quits the app and restarts it later.

Please can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: For that u have to use any persistence storage method like plist.

Comment: I am new to the development. Can you give me any links.

Comment: CRDave, this probably isn't the best way at all. Its just some text, faffing with plists and writing to files isn't going to be the best option. `NSUserDefaults` was created for this exact reason. And anything more complicated would be a job for SQLite/CoreData.

Comment: U r right But he just want to store a string and for storing a simple string I don't recommend to use a hole data base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` to store/retrieve your textfield data.

```
//To store
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"Hello World" forKey:@"anyKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


//To retrieve
yourTextField.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"anyKey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to use [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

NSUserDefaults are really a way to store settings and configuration options between sessions of an app (e.g. games might use this to "remember" if a user has selected to mute the sound).

You can use it for this however, it won't be a problem at all. Have a read through the class reference I have linked you to above, and come back and ask any questions if you get stuck.

Comment: I tried this. But there was no effect.             NSString *savestring = mileagerate.text; 
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
    [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstring"];
    [defaults setObject:savestring forKey:@"savedstring"]; 
    [defaults synchronize];

Comment: Cool, glad I could help you. :) No problem - I hate seeing people get downvoted for asking perfectly reasonable questions because its a little bit confusing. Thought you might get more help if I reworded it for you.

Answer (score 0):

store the value in NSUserDefaults standardDefaults ,the first time you enter the values like this,..

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults]setValue:textField.text forKey:@"username"]; //key is user defined
```

then

check

```
if (! [[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults]valueForkey:@"username"]isEqualToString:@""]){
        textField.text =(NSString *) [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults]valueForkey:@"username"];
    }
```